# Is there a way to dynamically build a function from a given domain to a given codomain?

Tags: types, elm

Can a function like this be implemented?
The function would have the type:

`f : (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> Maybe (a -> d)`

such that, if `b` and `c` are the same type when called, we return `Just (a -> d)` otherwise `Nothing`.

If not, is there a way to create our own types to represent functions such that we could implement this idea?

Comment: No, for better or for worse Elm code cannot inspect types during runtime, so there is no way to know if that first argument returned a `b` or a `c`. You could force them to be the same type (by using the same variable name).

Comment: I'm curious, how are you planning to use a function like this, if it was possible?

Comment: I am thinking about building a set of functions which will act as a data querying DSL. There will be different ways to compose these functions, but in some cases, if they are rearranged, there will be an improvement in performance. I don't expect I can do this but wanted to see what others have to say.

Comment: This is, as far as I know (not posting as answer because I do not consider my understanding to be good enough to be entirely definite in my answers) not (safely) possible in Elm nor Haskell nor any other (ML-typed or otherwise) language, because it breaks the 'Parametricity' principle: you're not allowed to inspect what type 'b' or 'c' are. In Haskell, there is an escape hatch known as the 'Typeable' typeclass, which, when constraining the function by it, _does_ allow you to inspect the concrete types. But Elm does not have such a measure.

Comment: @Qqwy This makes sense. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. And if we find contradictory information in the future, we'll deal with it then.